# Is my MAC monitored?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, isp, mac-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is your MAC address revealed when you hit up a website?](https://superuser.com/questions/114110/is-your-mac-address-revealed-when-you-hit-up-a-website)

Is the MAC address traceable to the **ISP**? Or any **website**? 
If so can we hide the MAC address from a **second person**?
What are persistent details sent over the Network while transmitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAC addresses are only visible at the final level of transmission. In a home setting, it's visible to the router, but not past the router.

Comment: consider a scenario a person has hacked a website. IP address can be traced from ISP. will they get any other details? If the person has used over a cafe shop with no surveillance how will the victim be traced?

Comment: @sp-gounder: The only way to find a MAC address is by looking at the logs of the cafe's router. If those logs don't exist, there is no way to get the MAC address.